Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown
estoy intentando redireccionar al usuario cuando completa la acción de la petición post que hace al completar el formulario, todo me da un código 200 pero a la hora de ya para finalizar redireccionar al usuario me salta lo siguiente
Error: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.
Os dejo el código por aquí
private async Task CrearSuscripcion() {
try {
    var respuesta = await http.PostAsJsonAsync(
        $"{Data.GlobalService.uri}/Cliente/CrearSuscripciones?Importe={suscripcion.Importe}&IVA={suscripcion.IVA}",
        suscripcion
    );


    if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        try {
            JsonDocument data = JsonDocument.Parse(content);
            if (data.RootElement.TryGetProperty("id", out JsonElement suscripcionID)) {
                int IdSusbscripcion = suscripcionID.GetInt32();

                if (IdSusbscripcion != 0) {
                    var suscripcionId = IdSusbscripcion;
                    var asociarRespuesta = await http.PostAsJsonAsync(
                        $"{Data.GlobalService.uri}/Cliente/AsociarSuscripciones?IdSuscripciones={suscripcionId}&IdDispositivo={suscripcion.IdDispositivo}",
                        new { SuscripcionId = suscripcionId }
                    );

                    if (asociarRespuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                        NavHome(); // Este es el proble,a
                    } else {
                        string errorMessage = await asociarRespuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ;
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error al procesar la respuesta JSON: " + ex.Message);
        }
    } else {
        string errorMessage = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Error al crear la suscripción: " + errorMessage);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
}

}
public void NavHome() {
    navManager.NavigateTo("/Admin/AdminSuscripciones/" + id + "/" + rol);
}


Es un bug, actualiza el visual studio. Yo hoy temprano lo actualicé y no puede reproducir el problema, así que quizás lo corrigieron

Hola @Yussef, actualicé visual studio pero el error sigue castigando, gracias por tu comentario, investigaré más. :) <3

Es un bug se salta según algunas condiciones, y como todo bug no se sabe muy bien porque pasa.
NavigationManager.NavigateTo produce una "Excepción silenciosa" dada ciertas circunstancias. Esta excepción no debería darte ningún problema, salvo que envolvieras esta función en un bloque try/catch tal como es tu caso.
Lo primero que hay que hace es dejar de monitoriar está excepción para que el Visual Studio no moleste. Para esto vas al menú de arriba > depurar > Ventanas > Configuración de Excepciones y en Commond Language Runtine Exception desmarcas Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException

Si no te aparece la opción, entonces no es necesario es paso

Luego hay que reorganizar tu código, para sacar NavigationManager.NavigateTo fuera del try/catch, algo así:
private async Task CrearSuscripcion()
{
    if (await IsCrearSuscripcion()){
        NavHome();
    }
}

private async Task<Boolean> IsCrearSuscripcion()
{
    try
    {
        await Subscribir();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}

private async Task Subscribir()
{
    var respuesta = await http.PostAsJsonAsync($"{Data.GlobalService.uri}/Cliente/CrearSuscripciones?Importe={suscripcion.Importe}&IVA={suscripcion.IVA}", suscripcion);

    if (!respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode){
        string errorMessage = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Error al crear la suscripción: " + errorMessage);
    }

    JsonDocument data = JsonDocument.Parse(content);
    if (!data.RootElement.TryGetProperty("id", out JsonElement suscripcionID))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("JSON Incorrecto");

    int IdSusbscripcion = suscripcionID.GetInt32();
    if (IdSusbscripcion == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ID Incorrecto");


    var asociarRespuesta = await http.PostAsJsonAsync($"{Data.GlobalService.uri}/Cliente/AsociarSuscripciones?IdSuscripciones={suscripcionId}&IdDispositivo={suscripcion.IdDispositivo}",new { SuscripcionId = suscripcionId });
    if (!asociarRespuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string errorMessage = await asociarRespuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Error al crear la suscripción: " + errorMessage);
    }
}


Eres un dios jaja, perdón por no contestar antes, era fin de semana y no estaba en mi entorno de trabajo. El problema se solucionó cuando quité los try catch del código, muchas gracias. Feliz Semana!
